# is there anyway to avoid this serialization behavior in cuda profiling?

Tags: cuda, nvvp

According to [CUDA streams not overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070392/cuda-streams-not-overlapping) , "the profiler will serialize streaming to get accurate timing data".
Now the question is, is there anyway to avoid this serialization behavior in cuda profiling (say nvvp)?
I am using Fermin M2090 and cuda-4.0.

Comment: You could always check the Nvidia site for the latest version of CUDA and it's document, as well as the new features it provides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Visual Profiler 5.0 (including nvprof and CUPTI) and Nsight Visual Studio Edition 2.0 and greater (>2 years old) support concurrent kernel trace for Fermi and Kepler devices.

Comment: Could you tell me which version support that? I didn't find it from the manual.

Comment: Simply download the latest toolkit. I believe 4.1/4.2 should support this as well but I'm not sure.